# InstallShield Custom Action failing because user installing in 64-bit Program Files directory?

Tags: windows, installshield-le

I have a 32-bit legacy application that allows users to specify the install path as part of the setup (pretty normal stuff...). I also have a custom action defined that runs a silent background install of another required bit of software after the initial installation is complete.

All is well when users install to the 32-bit Program Files (x86) directory.

Where I am running into problems is when users specify the 64-bit installation directory, Windows automagically changes the install path in the background to use the (x86) Program Files folder, which is fine, except that my custom actions that use the same INSTALLDIR property after the initial install is finished still think that it should be the 64-bit "Program Files" path - so the install fails when the custom action can't find the EXE file it's looking for.

My program is essentially exactly the same as the one described here by another developer but never resolved in that forum: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-216268.html

Does anyone have a clue what a valid workaround for this is? It seems pretty basic that an installer should not fail just because users think they should install to "C:\Program Files\Appname" instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\AppName".

I did peruse the similar questions on here but I don't see anyone else with this issue using custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you need to change to a 64 bit template to install to program files. General information in the tree > Template summary > change to x64;1033. At least one file needs to be marked as 64 bit in each directory. It is a check box on the component property. Be sure to check your custom actions still obey run conditions on major upgrades. I am having issues with that currently. Major upgrades on mine is set to remove all and it runs all custom actions no matter the conditions on the removal portion of the script.

Comment: Where can I get to the Template summary? I'm using Limited Edition, and I don't see it anywhere.